# DatagridViewCheckBoxColumn positioning the checkbox to the left with text following it

Tags: .net, datagridviewcheckboxcell

i had created a custom checkbox cell and column just to display a text along with the checkbox. the custom paint gets the bounds and paints the string. 
the issue i have is, the checkbox is always @ center. and the text follows it. 
On the other hand, i want the checkbox to appear to the left corner and the text to follow it from there.

Comment: can you show us some of your code ?

Comment: Okay, i got it. I was setting the DefaultCellStyle of the dataGridview it had no effect. But while manually creating the checkbox column had a debug point to tell me that the defaultCellStyle.Alignment wasnt as i had set. I again set it to middle left and things worked perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, i got it. I was setting the DefaultCellStyle of the dataGridview it had no effect. But while manually creating the checkbox column had a debug point to tell me that the defaultCellStyle.Alignment wasnt as i had set. I again set it to middle left and things worked perfect. Thanks!